How to create an adaptive horizontal scroller without gaps between cards when the card count isn't a multiple of the panel size?
I’m building a horizontal scroller in React for a set of cards, where each card takes up 1/3 of the view width. My scroller works correctly when the number of cards is a multiple of 3 (like 6 cards) because I use two divs as "panels," each holding three cards.
slider.current.style.width = `${totalPanels * 100}vw`;

Each panel is currently declared using divs, which leads to unnecessary gaps between cards when the total card count doesn’t evenly fit into the panel structure. For example:
When I have 6 cards, the scroller works as expected because I use two divs, each containing three cards.
But when I have 7 cards, the scroller ends up with 66% empty space in the last panel the panel structure doesn't adapt to the number of cards.

My Requirements
Adaptive to Card Count: The scroller should adapt dynamically to any card count, without requiring a set number of panels.
Seamless Layout: The scroller should avoid any unnecessary gaps between cards due to panel divs.
Consistent Card Width: Each card should always take up 33% of the viewport width.

Here is the relevant code:
import React, { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
import "tailwindcss/tailwind.css";
import BusinessSuccess from "../BusinessSuccess/BusinessSuccess";
import ChildCards from "../ChildCards/ChildCards";

gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

const HorizontalScroller = () => {
  const component = useRef();
  const slider = useRef();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let ctx = gsap.context(() => {
      const panels = gsap.utils.toArray(".panel");
      const totalPanels = panels.length;

      // Set the dynamic width of the slider based on panel count
      slider.current.style.width = `${totalPanels * 100}vw`;

      gsap.to(panels, {
        xPercent: -100 * (totalPanels - 1),
        ease: "none",
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: slider.current,
          pin: true,
          scrub: 1,
          snap: 1 / (totalPanels - 1),
          end: () => "+=" + slider.current.offsetWidth,
        },
      });
    }, component);
    return () => ctx.revert();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div ref={component} className="overflow-hidden">
      <div ref={slider} className="flex h-screen">
        <div className="panel w-screen h-screen flex items-center justify-center bg-grayBg">
          <BusinessSuccess />
        </div>
        <div className="panel bg-blackBg">
          <ChildCards startIndex={0} endIndex={3} />
        </div>
        <div className="panel bg-blackBg">
          <ChildCards startIndex={3} endIndex={6} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default HorizontalScroller;


import React from "react";
import ContainerComponent from "./modules/ContainerComponent";
import containersData from "./containersData";

const ChildCards = ({ startIndex, endIndex }) => {
  return (
    <div className="relative space-x-0">
      <div className="flex overflow-x-auto whitespace-nowrap w-screen scrollbar-hide scroll-container">
        {containersData.slice(startIndex, endIndex).map((containerData, index) => (
          <ContainerComponent
            key={index}
            logo={containerData.logo}
            heading={containerData.heading}
            number={containerData.number}
            text={containerData.text}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChildCards;


// ContainerComponent.js
import React from "react";
import './index.css';
import AnimatedBackground from "../../../utilities/AnimatedBackground/AnimatedBackground";

const ContainerComponent = ({ logo, heading, number, text }) => (
  <AnimatedBackground>
    <div className="glow-right-container flex-shrink-0 w-[33vw] h-screen flex flex-col border-r-2 border-neon p-10">
      
      {/* First Div - Icon Section (50% height) */}
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-1/2">
        <img src={logo} className="w-32 aspect-square" alt="Icon" />
      </div>

      {/* Second Div - Content Section (50% height, aligned to top) */}
      <div className="glow-content flex flex-col justify-start items-start h-1/2">
        
        {/* Heading and Number */}
        <div className="w-full flex justify-between items-center mb-2">
          <h1 className="text-[40px] font-monument text-white">{heading}</h1>
          <span className="text-[40px] font-mulish text-neon">
            {number}
          </span>
        </div>

        {/* Paragraph Text */}
        <p className="font-mulish text-[20px] text-left text-white whitespace-normal break-words leading-loose">
          {text}
        </p>
        
      </div>

    </div>
  </AnimatedBackground>
);

export default ContainerComponent;


My Current Attempt
I've tried using fixed panel divs to wrap the cards, but it seems inefficient, especially when the number of cards doesn’t match the panel count. Here’s what I’m aiming for:
Map each card directly, applying a 33% width style to each card.
Make the scroller responsive to the card count instead of dividing into fixed panels.

How can I refactor my code so that the scroller adapts dynamically to any number of cards and each card has a consistent width with no gaps between them?
Thanks in advance for any help!
